# Puppet exec: shell command returns "could not find command"

Tags: hyperlink, terminal, exec, puppet

It's the first time I'm using an `exec` with Puppet but I'm not sorting out why it continues returning errors. The command I'm executing consists in a series of symbolic link creations, code is:

```
exec { "creation_of_symbolic_links":
     command => "ln -s link1dest link1name; ln -s link2dest link2name; ... ; ln -s linkNdest linkNname",
     path => "/etc", #added just in order to delete an error
}
```

All linkdests and linknames are absolute paths. The error returned is:

> Error: Could not find command 'ln'
>
> Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[nodename]/Exec[creation_of symbolic_links]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: Could not find command 'ln'

How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read about the meaning of [path](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#exec-attribute-path) parameter in [exec](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#exec) resource. 
You got an error because path is not properly defined. 
Try using:

```
path =>  [ '/bin/', '/sbin/' , '/usr/bin/', '/usr/sbin/' ]
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. But I'm still not understanding why: given that I used only absolute paths, shouldn't the execution path be irrelevant?

Comment: Hi - from you given example you are not using absolte paths to the command `ln`. The absole path would have been `/bin/ln` or whatever `which ln` on your distro says. The solution provided by @kkamilpl makes it possible to use the command without the absolute paths since the system will look under the defined paths for the given command.